# append items in an array one by one, with delay, and repeat when all items where exhausted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of words (text) which I'd like to append one by one to a target div with a small delay after each word has been appended. I'm currently able to do that with the code below.

```
var showText = function (target, text, index, interval) {
  if (index < text.length) {
    $(target).append(text[index++]);
    setTimeout(function () { showText(target, text, index, interval); }, interval);
  }
}
```

However, I'd also like for the script to once the last word in the array has been appended go to the start of the array again and keep appending words to the target for a new cycle. I'd like to define the number of cycles the process will run.

I thought nesting loops would be the solution as below

```
  (function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      (function myloop (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(target).append(text[i]);
          if (i > 0) {
            myLoop(i);
          }
        }, 1000);
      })(10);
    }
  })
```

but for some reason this is repeating each word of the array 3 times rather than cycling through the array 3 times. I think I'm getting confused on how to use JS with this loops. Could you help me untangle this?

Comment: I'd suggest remove `if` and use `%` operator to fetch word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented before, use `%` operator instead and update your `if` condition for *Max Limit* only.

#### Sample

```js
function appendWords(arr, index, maxRepeat) {
  if (++index >= arr.length * maxRepeat) return;
  var word = arr[(index % arr.length)];
  document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML += " " + word;
  initTimeout(arr, index, maxRepeat)
}

function initTimeout(arr, index, max) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    appendWords(arr, index, max)
  }, 1000)
}

function main() {
  var arr = ['test', 'foo', 'world', 'bar'];
  var index = -1;
  initTimeout(arr, index, 2)
}

main();
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Rajesh thanks so much for the detail approach. If you have a minute to spare could you explain the role of the % operator in the context of the third line of code and it's advantages Vs the previous if statement

Comment: `%` means [mod operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) will give you `remainder`. Only benefit is, your index will always be inside bounds. Also, having `setTimeout` inside loop can have issues as loop will run very quickly. But this is just an opinionated call.

Comment: Thanks a lot it make sense!

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse your existing method within a new function that has a `cycles` option.

```
function showTextCycles(target, text, interval, cycles) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            showText(target, text, 0, interval)
        }, i * interval * text.length)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it does work. I'll give it a look to understand better how it works. Why i and interval and text.length are multiplied?

Comment: Basically, `interval * text.length` is the time that it takes to complete a single cycle. Since we are running the loop synchronously (all at a single instant, give or take a few ms) we have to plan all cycles in advance: for cycle 0, we start now; for cycle 1, we start at `1 * (interval * text.length)`; for cycle 2, start at `2 * (interval * text.length)`, etc.